# jquery check if "this" object is hovered or not, not using .is(':hover') function

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I am building the cover for an album. The cover will start looping through all images in it when the mouse is hover onto any of the image, else it stops looping, and it will repeat the process. I had the following function (modified from jQuery documentation) that does most of the job.

But I got stuck at the noHover() function, it is supposed to check the return value of this.is(':hover') to see if the current image is being hovered or not. However, this function only works in my firefox and does not work on other browsers. I then used $('#images:hover').length. But this checks if the div is hovered or not, not exactly the current image that is being examined. Is this any way I could check if the "this" object is hovered so that when the white area in div is hovered, it will not loop the images.

**JSFiddle demo**  http://jsfiddle.net/91q54zj6/

```
$(function(){

    $('.noncover').hide(); // hide all the non-cover pictures

    function noHover() {
        // check div is hovered or not
        return $('#images:hover').length ? this : this.wait('mouseenter');
    }

    $('.cover').mouseenter(function() {


        $('#images > img').repeat().each($).fadeIn(50,$).wait(100).wait(noHover).fadeOut(50,$);

    });
```

Comment: wait(noHover)? to return this if it is being hovered, so no wait, if not hovered, then wait, until mouse is over again.

Comment: Can you show some example just too see exactly how this cover album slide thing works?

Comment: Hi andrex, please see the updated solution by Ryan, this is what I expect for the cover of the album. so basically like a quick view of the photos inside. http://jsfiddle.net/91q54zj6/1/

Comment: I can't find the `wait` method in the jQuery documentation. is it a third-party plugin?

Comment: yes, it used the timing API of jQuery, here is the documentation page: http://creativecouple.github.io/jquery-timing/api/wait/.wait_deferred.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using find() and img:hover:

```
return $('#images').find('img:hover').length ? this : this.wait('mouseenter');
```

I updated your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/91q54zj6/1/

Comment: Thank you Ryan, that solves the problem. Btw, just curious, seeing lots of people saying .is(':hover') only breaks for jQuery 1.9.1 and above. But how come it is not the same issue for me? I used 1.8.3 and it only works on chrome, is this normal? thanks!

Comment: I tried the updated Fiddle in IE, Chrome and Safari; it worked in all of them. The :hover CSS selector is supported in all major browsers now, so you shouldn't run into issues there. Your original code was checking if the mouse was hovering over the entire div, not the individual images within the div. The find() function will search immediate children of the current object and apply an optional filter. Here, to search for images that are being hovered, you'd use the filter "img:hover". Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ryan. I find the is(':hover') function work in all browsers in JSfiddles too. But stops working if I double click my html file from localhost, it only works in Firefox in this case. Do you know the difference by any chance?